# exclamation marks around a string in yaml

Tags: yaml, openmaptiles

In a yaml config file created by [OpenMapTiles](https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles)  I found the following syntax:

```
table: (SELECT geometry, class FROM layer_water(!bbox!, z(!scale_denominator!)))
```

The strings enclosed in exclamation marks obviously will be substituted by some provided values. My question is, how would this be done? I did not find anything about such a syntax for variable substition in yaml. Can someone please point me in the right direction?
Or is this meant to be dealed with AFTER parsing yaml?

Regards Oliver

Comment: Well it is definitely not part of YAML. However I cannot tell you which component takes care of replacing those substrings. Possibly the DB layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.
The syntax is special to [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) and in my case to the [PostGIS Plugin](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PostGIS#bbox-token).
The PostGIS plugin supports several special tokens. You can use them in subqueries and Mapnik will replace them at render time.